# Pullback of a differential form by the zero section

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

Let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle of rank $n$ and  let $j: M \rightarrow E$ be its zero section.

Let $\beta$ be a closed differential form. I was convinced  that $j^* \beta$ is the zero form, until I found the theorem which says that if $\beta$ is closed differential form in $\Omega(E)$, then $${(2 \pi)}^{-n/2}\int_E U \wedge \beta = \int_M j^*\beta$$
Where $U$ is a Thom form for the vector bundle $E$.

After reading this theorem I realize that $j^* \beta$ may not be the zero form. Please someone explains to me what is the form $j^* \beta$ ?

Comment: Why do you think $j^*\beta$ is the zero form?

Comment: @ Michael Albanese , it's because of the following: Let $m \in M$ and  let $X_1, ...,X_k$ be tangent vectors in $T_mM$ , then $(j^*\beta)_m(X_1,...,X_k)= \beta_{j(m)}(j_* X_1,...,j_*X_k) = \beta_{0_m}(j_* X_1,...,j_*X_k) $, if we denotes $\gamma_i(t),$ the integral curve of $X_i$, then $ j_*X_i = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}j(\gamma)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}0 =0 $(since $j $ is the zero section), then since $ \beta_{0_m}$ is linear, ${(j^*\beta)}_m= 0.$

Comment: Your mistake is writing $j(\gamma) = 0$. What do you even mean by $0$? All you know is that $j(\gamma(0)) = j(m) = 0_m$, but the curve $j\circ\gamma$ need not be constant.

Comment: @Michael Albanese, Now I realize where was my mistake, thanks a lot! I have  another  question:  Now that I understand that $j^*\beta$ is not zero, I wonder if we can say something about it, or it is abstract like the pullback of $\beta$ by any other map ?

Comment: I don't think you can say much more than it is a pullback of a form by some map.

Comment: You’re justing integrating the $n$-form $\beta$ (which is a form on $E$) over the zero-section (which, of course, is a diffeomorphic copy of $M$). Indeed, because $\beta$ is closed, you get the same integral over the image of any section.

Comment: @Ted shiftin, could you please elaborate more on why is the image of a closed differential form $\beta$ under any section is the same?

Comment: Huh? I said integral. Two sections are homotopic, so their pullbacks of a cohomology class are equal.

Comment: Ah ok, I actually didn't know this! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, $j^*\beta$ is not necessarily the zero form. The point is that for $X \in T_mM$, we need not have $j_*(X) = 0 \in T_{j(m)}E = T_{0_m}E$.

An illustrative example is the trivial line bundle $\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $\pi(x, y) = x$ where now $j : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $j(x) = (x, 0)$. If $\beta$ is a $1$-form, then $\beta = fdx + gdy$ for some smooth functions $f, g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, so

$$j^*\beta = (f\circ j)d(x\circ j) + (g\circ j)d(y\circ j) = (f\circ j)dx.$$

Note that $(f\circ j)(x) = f(j(x)) = f(x, 0)$ which can be an arbitrary function of $x$, so every one-form on $\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $j^*\beta$ for some one-form $\beta$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Michael Albanese, thank you very much for this nice example!